# application.yml not picked up by hystrix

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix, netflix, spring-cloud-netflix

i want to move the below configuration in the method annotation to property file

```
@HystrixCommand(commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds", value = "10000"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds", value = "10000"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold", value = "5"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage", value = "100")   
    },
            fallbackMethod = "fallbackCall")
```

I have places the application.yml file under src/main/resources

```
hystrix:
  command.:
    getResult:
      circuitBreaker:
        sleepWindowInMilliseconds: 10000
        errorThresholdPercentage: 100
        requestVolumeThreshold: 5
      metrics:
        rollingStats:
          timeInMilliseconds: 10000
```

I am not using spring boot. This file is not getting picked up by Hystrix.

Is there any configuration need to be done to pass the application.yml to hystrix configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

created as config.properties and it worked . 
This is by default looked up by archaius

```
hystrix.command.getResult.metrics.rollingStats.timeInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.getResult.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=5
hystrix.command.getResult.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=100
hystrix.command.getResult.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds=10000
```

Comment: There is a bridge and it does work. There must be an issue with your dependencies, how are you bringing in hystrix?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue, we are using Spring boot and Spring Cloud dependencies in our projects. Adding the below dependency has resolved the issue,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>${version-as-per-your-project}</version>
</dependency>
```

We were initially testing with below dependency which was causing the issue,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Have the same issue, and this dependency is already there, but the issue remains.